# How to add a meta information to the URL?

Tags: functions, url-rewriting, post-meta, urls

I need to put a post meta information to the URL:

www.website.com/custom-taxonomy/postname-[metainfo]

How to change the rewrite rules, that the content of this meta information is added to the URL?

I just figured out how to get the meta information from the post:

```
<?php $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_metainfo', true ); ?>
```

Many thanks for any support!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here. Do you need to use it for a specific reason

Comment: I need to have much more unique URLs, and therefore I need to add an ID to the URL, which is stored in the meta information.

Comment: Did you had a look at [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it seems to be the right way. I need the add_query_arg working under the following conditions: 1. instead of a fixed text, the post meta information should be added to the URL. 2. just working for a specific custom post type: www.website.com/custom-post-type/postname-[metainfo]

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution: Just add this code to your functions.php and replace '_metainfo' by your meta information and 'posttype' by your posttype.

```
function add_meta2url( $link, $post ) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_metainfo', true );
      if ( 'posttype' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $link = $link . '#' .$post_meta;
        return $link;
     }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'add_meta2url', 1, 2 );
```

Unfortunately, the '#' cannot be replaced by any other special character like '-', otherwise the url is responding with a 404 error message.

Comment: you could possibly make it work with a hyphen by hooking `parse_query` and removing the last hyphen and subsequent text so WordPress queries for the correct post name.